# how to use the index (array index) in the match statement in Karate feature file

Tags: karate

Below is my feature

Feature: f1

Scenario: S1

```
 * def values = [1]
    * def fun =
"""
function(values,index){
karate.call('pass-array-index.feature',{arrayIndexValue:index})
}
"""
    * karate.forEach(values, fun)
```

Below is my another feature file and feature name is pass-array-index.feature

```
Feature: f2

  Scenario: s2
    * def data = [1]
    * print arrayIndexValue
    Then match associatedRules[arrayIndexValue] == 1
```

My Expectation was arrayIndexValue variable will resolve to 0 however got below error.

Could not parse token starting at position 1. Expected ?, ', 0-9, *

src/test/java/research/pass-array-index.feature:6

There is a issue with the variable arrayIndexValue with used with match statement and this is not getting resolved. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To force `match` expressions to be evaluated as JS and not JsonPath, enclose in round brackets. This should work:

```
Then match (associatedRules[arrayIndexValue]) == 1
```

Explained here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#json-lookup

Comment: Its working fine now, Thank you.  I still did not get where exactly it has been explained in the documentation, I have gone through the documentation link shared above but did not get it.

Comment: @ShreyanshJain sorry I had the wrong link, fixed it. it is a very brief explanation though